How to empty electrum wallet
How can I create a transaction in the Electrum Bitcoin Wallet application, such that my balance becomes 0 BTC?
I have an old wallet with 0.00760578 BTC in it. I'd like to create a transaction that sends all of this to another address, but if I try in Electrum to create a transaction that's exactly 0.00760578, it will say that I don't have enough funds for the fee.
If I try to reduce the transaction amount and target, say, 20 sat/vB for the fee, then I run the risk of having some left-over coins because I can't know the exact size of the transaction.
Is there a way to tell electrum: "I want to send a transaction with 20 sat/vB for the fee, and just send every remaining satoshi to X address"?

You can simply go to the send tab, enter an address and description and press the Max button. This will send the largest possible amount minus fees to the address. See this screenshot of Electrum Version 4.5.8:


Does this amount get adjusted automatically when I change the fee in the next step? For example, if I decrease the fee from 50 sat/vB (that electrum auto-selected) to 11 sat/vB, will it increase the amount of the transaction automatically at this later step?

@helpless-grip yes, it does exactly this. If you click pay you can adjust the fee in the popup window and the sent amount will automatically be adjusted and shown to you.
